# Как реализовать функцию, которая убирала бы надпись из текстового поля?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим есть `<input type="text">`, как сделать так, чтобы в нём отображалась надпись по умолчанию, но при начале ввода, она бы пропадала?

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать?  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1051920/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-js-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Введите сюда что-то" />
```

```js
function clearInput(id) {
  var inp = document.getElementById(id);

  flag = true;

  inp.oninput = function() {
    if (flag) {
      this.value = "";
      flag = false;
    }
  }
}

clearInput("inp");
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" value="Что-то" />
```